# Android ScrollView+TableLayout+AutoCompleteTextView throws ClassCastException

Tags: android, android-layout, autocompletetextview, android-tablelayout, android-scrollview

I created a layout that looks like this:

```
       <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
       <TableLayout 
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent">
       <TableRow>
        <TextView 
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        </TableRow>
        <TableRow>
              <TextView 
                    android:text="Name"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              />
              <AutoCompleteTextView android:id="@+id/name"
                                    android:layout_width="150dp"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
       </TableRow>
       </TableLayout>
       </ScrollView>
```

This throws a `ClassCastException` while using the `TextView` without a `TableRow` surrounding it does not. Why?

Comment: exception is not because of your xml..its because of your code.post your code..

Comment: Also you're using an `AutoCompleteTextView` that makes use of an `Adapter` when displaying the results. This will not work in your case because you're using it in a `ScrollView`

Comment: you have not closed the first textview tab,first close it

Comment: I am using an ArrayAdapter<String> with the AutoCompleteTextView.What alternative will work?